# Есть ли в стандарной библиотеке функция подсчета количества раз вхождений одинаковых элементов?

Tags: c++

Например, сколько в векторе целых чисел, троек?

Comment: Давайте в этот раз вы сами посмотрите на предыдущие свои вопросы и в моих ответах найдете ответ. У функции очень простое и понятное имя.

Хотя никто не мешает использовать std::accumulate:)

Comment: Функция find, наверно.

Comment: ее придется вызывать в цикле. Но есть более прямой способ. Одной функцией.

Comment: accumulate и в ее последнем параметре find?

Comment: Так можно написать (хотя просто так последним параметром find не получиться использовать).

Вот я не понимаю, неужели сложно открыть справку по функции std::find и найти там ссылку на другу, которая решает проблему? Или английский совсем не знаем?

Comment: совсем мало и с переводчиком все. вопщем если я функции не знаю то я пишу ее сам - вот так выкручиваюсь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы посчитать, сколько раз заданное значение встречается в векторе или другом контейнере, С++14 вариант:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::count
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> // std::cbegin, std::cend
#include <vector>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  vector<int> v = { 1, 3, 2, 3, 4 };
  cout << count(cbegin(v), cend(v), 3) << endl;
}
```

C++11:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::count
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  vector<int> v = { 1, 3, 2, 3, 4 };
  cout << count(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), 3) << endl;
}
```

Более общий C++11 вариант:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::count
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> // std::begin, std::end
#include <vector>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  vector<int> v = { 1, 3, 2, 3, 4 };
  cout << count(begin(v), end(v), 3) << endl;
}
```

C++98:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::count
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  int a[] = { 1, 3, 2, 3, 4 };
  vector<int> v(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a));
  cout << count(v.begin(), v.end(), 3) << endl;
}
```