# Число повторений символа в строке

Tags: c++, строки

Есть ли какие-либо библиотечные функции в [с++](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%2b%2b) для подсчета количества конкретного символа в строке `std::string`?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Есть ли в стандарной библиотеке функция подсчета количества раз вхождений одинаковых элементов?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/370381/23044)

Answer (score 7):

Есть конечно же.

Название - очевидное - [std::count](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/):

```
// count algorithm example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::count
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main () {

  int myints[] = {10,20,30,30,20,10,10,20};   // 8 elements
  int mycount = std::count (myints, myints+8, 10);
  std::cout << "10 appears " << mycount << " times.\n";

  // подсчет числа элементов:
  std::vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+8);
  mycount = std::count (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), 20);
  std::cout << "20 appears " << mycount  << " times.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Забавно - даже не вспомнил, начал вспоминать функции в `string`...

Comment: а оно работает быстрее чем самописная?

Comment: @pavel смотря какая самописная. Но уж точно не медленнее, ибо алгоритм тривиален.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(void){
    std::string s = "aaabla-blaaa";
    std::cout << std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), 'a') << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть в algorithm function template std::count_if

Comment: `count_if` для подсчета по предикату. По значению - просто `count`.